# Why does the wallet contract convert addresses to integers?

Tags: solidity, arrays

In the `multiowned` part of the [wallet contract](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/js/src/contracts/snippets/wallet.sol), owners are stored in a `uint` array, such as in [line 59](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/js/src/contracts/snippets/wallet.sol#L59) in the constructor. Here is a relevant excerpt:

```
contract multiowned {

  // METHODS

  function multiowned(address[] _owners, uint _required) {
    m_numOwners = _owners.length + 1;
    m_owners[1] = uint(msg.sender);
    m_ownerIndex[uint(msg.sender)] = 1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < _owners.length; ++i)
    {
      m_owners[2 + i] = uint(_owners[i]);
      m_ownerIndex[uint(_owners[i])] = 2 + i;
    }
    m_required = _required;
  }

  // FIELDS

  uint[256] m_owners;
  mapping(uint => uint) m_ownerIndex;
  // why not address[] m_owners and mapping(address => uint) m_ownerIndex ?
}
```

Why not store them in `address`-type variables? Is there a special reason for this? Does it make the storage lighter?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think in the code he uses `uint` instead address because as you know an array needs an integer as index.and the idea behind if i understand well the snippet it is to return the index of the participant or an owner (while there is multiple owners) using its address without using a loop.

for example if the first sender is `0X123` and the "nth" adress is `0x555`
but we don't know the order n.
we need just to call `m_ownerIndex[uint(0x555)]` to get the value of n without a loop.

if you use an address array for the same example you will need something like

```
for(int i=0,i<;i++)
{
if (m_ownerIndex[i]==0X555)
return i;break;
}
```

Comment: Yes, an extra index variable is necessary in Solidity arrays. But why is the array not an address array, and why convert them to integers every time?

Comment: As i said you can do it by using adress by then you will need to use a loop or double array.so to keep it simple the developer used the address as an index.

Comment: I don't think -or don't understand how- that's the case. If we converted them to addresses, the code should be exactly the same, maybe even simpler since we won't need `uint()`'s around addresses.

Comment: try to rewrite the code using address and you will get what i am talking about

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind. Unfortunately I couldn't find the time. Now I read more carefully and I think I see your point. I think, using what I propose you can also get n without a loop, like `m_ownerIndex[0x555]`, although not sure :) Wouldn't this work too?